# Google Charts API datetime unix format?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-visualization

I'm having a hard time getting Google Charts to understand the datetime format. I used an example [1] where the datetime format is set to a simple month day and year, but I changed it to take an input of type datetime. An example is available the following page:

http://www.sccs.swarthmore.edu/users/09/leo/cgi-bin/viewer.php

The start of the code is as follows:

```
data.addColumn('datetime', 'Date');
data.addColumn('number', 'Active or not');      
data.addRows(1768);
data.setValue(0, 0, new Date(1306192258));
data.setValue(0, 1, 1);
```

Why will Google change that Date format to Jan 15, 1970? (Start of Epoch time?)

Thanks!

[1] http://www.beakkon.com/geek/how-to/create-interactive-charts-using-google-charts-api

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
data.addColumn('datetime', 'Date');
data.addColumn('number', 'Active or not');      
data.addRows(1768);
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(1306192258*1000);
data.setValue(0, 0, d);
data.setValue(0, 1, 1);
```

Comment: could you add a short explanation why multiplying the number with 1000 would solve it? Is it a matter of seconds vs milliseconds?

Comment: Nevermind, I found out that the javascript function setTime() uses milliseconds, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Some more info on the Javascript Date function can be found [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp) website
I found - new Date("July 21, 2011 02:00:00") to be a good compromise for what I wanted to do.

Snippet of my code

```
data.addRows([
[new Date("July 21, 2011 00:00:00"), 0.319636363636 ],
[new Date("July 21, 2011 07:00:00"), 0.319636363636 ],
[new Date("July 21, 2011 22:00:00"), 0.319636363636 ],
[new Date("July 21, 2011 23:00:00"), 0.319636363636 ],
[new Date("July 22, 2011 09:00:00"), 0.319636363636 ],
[new Date("July 22, 2011 10:00:00"), 0.319636363636 ]
]);
```