# google charts datetime type

Tags: datetime, google-visualization, annotatedtimeline

Is it possible to use literal strings when instantiating a datetime type?  (If no, skip)  If so, does the - need to be a /?  If that doesn't matter, please tell me what's wrong with this:

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({cols:[{label: 'date', type: 'datetime'}, 
      {label: 'power', type: 'number'}], rows: [{c: [{v:2007/12/01 00:12:00},{v:0}]}, 
      {c: [{v:2007/12/01 01:12:00},{v:101}]}, {c: [{v:2007/12/01 02:12:00},{v:201}]}, 
      {c: [{v:2007/12/01 03:12:00},{v:302}]}]});

(I already tried quoting literal datetimes.)
-Shawn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to put it in Epoch format. try something like this

```
new Date("#epoch_seconds_go_here");
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158223/google-charts-api-datetime-unix-format) is the link that might help you

Comment: it does need to be instantiated, yes.